# How JPA knows when it have to throw OptimisticLockException?

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to have confirmation of the following :

```
public void test() {

   SomeEntity se = em.find(SomeEntity.class, 1);

   // Do something...

   se.setField = "test";

}
```

Here JPA will perform only optimistic check on `se`.

Next :

```
public void test() {

   SomeEntity se = em.find(SomeEntity.class, 1);
   SomeOtherEntity soe = em.find(SomeOtherEntity.class, 1);
   em.lock(soe, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);

   // Do something...

   se.setField = "test";

}
```

Here JPA will throw OptimisticException if `se` OR `soe` have been changed (version incremented in database) since last read.

Is that true ?

Comment: Not sure about when the OLE is thrown. I believe it's thrown after `se` or `soe` have been changed **and** you try to update them. I mean `se.setField("New Value");` alone won't throw the exception but `se.setField("New Value"); em.merge(se); em.flush();` will.

Answer (score 0):

**OptimisticLockException** will be throw only when transaction commits to database ore you call `em.flush()` - then JPA Provider will compare version field and figure out that it was changed by another transactoin.